# Count lines between two values in RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I want to count the lines between 2 values in a Richtextbox, depending on if its easier if they are the same values or not i can edit the data which will be shown in the Richtextbox.

The Richtextbox will look like this:

```
--BEGIN1
ABC
DEF
GHI
KLM
--END1
--BEGIN2
NOP
QRS
TUV
--END2
```

and so on... i want to count the lines between the begin/end

I experimented with different ways but i cant get it to count between those values.

Idea behind it is to tell me if the number of lines between the values is correct or if theres a line missing which will add a warning to the text but i can figure that out my self, help with counting the lines between 2 values would be appreciated.

TiA

Comment: If you can get count of the number of elements and subtract 4, that may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Might be an idea to update your question with you best attempt so far and a clear description of how it doesn't meet requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the lines from the `RichTextBox` through the `Lines` property. Then loop through the lines and remember the index of the block start. When you encounter a block end, you can easily calculate the number of lines between the start and the current index.

```vb
Dim lines As String() = richTextBox1.Lines
Dim start As Integer
Dim blockNumber As String = ""

For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
    Dim line As String = lines(i)
    If line.StartsWith("--BEGIN") Then
        blockNumber = line.Substring(7)
        start = i
    ElseIf line.StartsWith("--END") Then
        Console.WriteLine($"Block # = {blockNumber}, Number of lines = {i - start - 1}")
    End If
Next
```

For your example this prints in a console test:

```
Block # = 1, Number of lines = 4
Block # = 2, Number of lines = 3
```

You will have to replace the `Console.WriteLine` by whatever you want to do with the result.

Comment: Assuming the values in the RichTextBox don't actually need any RTF formatting, I'd use `Dim lines As New List(Of String)(RichTextBox1.Lines)` so that you can easily INSERT and/or DELETE lines between your block markers and everything will shift automatically. Then you can just reassign the modified list back to the RTB with `RichTextBox1.Lines = lines.ToArray`.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, yes using the `Lines` property is better. I simplified my code accordingly.